# Why doesnt this script animate (jquery) 3 seconds after page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a banner (width 100%, height 150px) that is hidden (position relative, top -150px) at the load of document. I want to show it after 3 seconds, what am I doing wrong? This seems pretty straight forward?

```
$(function() {
    var t = setTimeout(popmenu(), 3000);

    function popmenu() {

        $('#bcktop').animate({ 
                top : "+=150" 
            }, 150
        );            
    }       
});
```

Comment: Have you tried $(window).load(function() instead of document.ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling popmenu rather than passing the function:

```
var t = setTimeout(popmenu(), 3000);
```

should be:

```
var t = setTimeout(popmenu, 3000);
```

Comment: Amazing, such a simple detail! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass a function reference into the `setTimeout` function. By sending the function like `this()`, you're sending the return value of that function to `setTimeout`.

Change this:

```
 var t = setTimeout(popmenu(), 3000);
```

to this:

```
 var t = setTimeout(popmenu, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery `.delay()` function:

```
$('#bcktop').delay(3000).animate({
  top: "+=150"
}, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding quotes around popmenu() and placing `function popmenu()` outside the `$(function() { });` fixes it:

```
$(function() {
    var t = setTimeout("popmenu()", 3000);
});

function popmenu() {

    $('#bcktop').animate({ 
           top : "+=150" 
       }, 150
    );            
}
```